# Experienced Python programmers (ESPECIALLY former php programmers) : How do I debug python?

Tags: python, debugging

In PHP, it was extremely easy to start hacking away and figuring out what was going on on a page.  Just throw in a bunch of echos and print_r's and that was about it.  It appears that this technique is not working for me in python.  I am getting practice by hacking around in a python photo upload module, and when a photo is uploaded, it creates 3 different size photos.  I found the code that does this, but I want to see the state at that particular moment.  I tried doing a "print" on the size variable, but it did not show up in my browser.

I guess a more straightforward question would  be, is it "pythonic" do debug using the browser ( equivalent to echo's and print_r's in php ), or is this what the python console is for?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `logging` module rather than printing stuff to stdout.

Using the interpreter in interactive mode is a great way to try out code, and `pdb` is very useful for real debugging.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up.  How, though, would I emulate uploading a picture through the console??  This is the part that is confusing me.  With php, I just find the view that is being executed, and print_r.  Then load the page, upload images, and look at the vars.  Can you quickly walk me through how to 1.emulate the photo upload, then 2. examine variables.  Again, step 1 is the confusing part for me.  Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: for something like that, `logging.debug()` is the way to go; depending on your web framework, `print` probably won't send anything to the response to the browser (and if it does, it might not do it in a useful way; often you end up accidentally writing to the HTTP headers)

Answer (score 0):

It's "pythonic" to do debugging using [the `pdb` module](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html).

But really, if you're just "hacking around", then I suggest messing around with an interactive interpreter interface, especially one that supports autocompletion (Python itself comes with IDLE right out of the box).

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to use a debugger ;)   Hacking with prints is cool for simple php, but you can save a lot of time in higher languages with a debugger.

As mentioned, PDP is a place to start http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Comment: I know how to use a debugger :P.  I am just thoroughly confused as to how to test a web page using a python command prompt.  See my first response to wooble's answer as to what is  confusing.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned PDB, I'll take the opportunity to sing the praises of Eclipse using the pydev plugin, which is absolutely fantastic.  IDLE is also well worth a go.  Both of these IDEs allow you to step through code, inspect variables, auto-complete, etc. etc.

http://pydev.org/

Download Eclipse then use the Software Updates menu to add in PyDev.

http://pydev.org/updates

Answer (score 0):

[PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) from [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com) is as good as all their other products.  It has an integrated debugger and lots more.